# How to assign values by property in nested object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, object

I would like to know how to assign values to object property in nested object by `id=insta` in javascript

I have a two objects, I need apply one object property to another using javascript

I got stuck and dont know how to proceed,

```
obj1.forEach(e=> {if(e.id==='insta') Object.assign(e, obj2)})
```

```
var obj1 = [
  {
    id: "insta",
    rate: "2.4",
    fee: "0",
    amount: "400"
  },
 {
    id: "trans",
    rate: "1.4",
    fee: "0",
    amount: "200"
  }
]

var obj2 = 
{
  data: {
     rate_value: "4.4",
     fee_value: "10",
     targetamount: "5000",
     country_code: "SG"
   }
}
```

```
Expected Output: 

res= [
  {
    id: "insta",
    rate: "4.4",
    fee: "10",
    amount: "5000",
    country_code: "SG"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want all the properties from obj2 to be in the res object or just country_code?

Comment: How do properties get mapped? that doesn't look like a reasonable criteria. `rate_value` becomes `rate`, while `targetamount` becomes `amount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to reduce the array to the result we intend to. Here I add the the `if` condition and mapping values from `obj2` in the callback of the `reduce` method. Basically the filtering and mapping is done, inside the `reduce` callback method.

```js
var obj1 = [{
    id: "insta",
    rate: "2.4",
    fee: "0",
    amount: "400"
  },
  {
    id: "trans",
    rate: "1.4",
    fee: "0",
    amount: "200"
  }
]

var obj2 = {
  data: {
    rate_value: "4.4",
    fee_value: "10",
    targetamount: "5000",
    country_code: "SG"
  }
}

const result = obj1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.id === 'insta') {
    acc.push({
      ...curr,
      rate: obj2.data.rate_value,
      fee: obj2.data.fee_value,
      amount: obj2.data.targetamount,
      country_code: obj2.data.country_code
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @brk Maybe its due to just answering the question not explaining. Boney You should explain the solution you have written. Maybe your solution is right and would help the OP. But can't help the other people seeing the answer later.

Comment: @Boney Update the answer with some kind of explanation I will upvote.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As your expected output shows you only want the items whose `id="insta"` so use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get those. Then use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create a temporary object inside map. And return the combined object using Spread Operator.

**Note:** You need to create another object because properties name in `obj2` and array are different.

```js
var obj1 = [ { id: "insta", rate: "2.4", fee: "0", amount: "400" }, { id: "trans", rate: "1.4", fee: "0", amount: "200" }]
var obj2 = { data: { rate_value: "4.4", fee_value: "10", targetamount: "5000", country_code: "SG" } }

const res = obj1.filter(x => x.id === "insta").map(x => {
  const {data} = obj2
  let temp = {
    rate : data.rate_value,
    fee : data.fee_value,
    amount : data.targetamount,
    country_code : data.country_code
  }
  return {...x,...temp}
})


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to contain object with `id = "insta"` then apply the data from `obj2` to each one of the items using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Something like that:

```js
var obj1 = [{
    id: 'insta',
    rate: '2.4',
    fee: '0',
    amount: '400',
  },
  {
    id: 'trans',
    rate: '1.4',
    fee: '0',
    amount: '200',
  },
];

var obj2 = {
  data: {
    rate_value: '4.4',
    fee_value: '10',
    targetamount: '5000',
    country_code: 'SG',
  },
};

const result = obj1
  .filter(item => item.id === 'insta')
  .map(item => ({
    id: item.id,
    rate: obj2.data.rate_value,
    fee: obj2.data.fee_value,
    amount: obj2.data.targetamount,
    country_code: obj2.data.country_code,
  }));
  
  console.log(result)
```